# SQL query to select data between two dates and times

Tags: sql, sql-server

There is a `[time]` field in my table, which is a DateTime variable, the format just like `2014-04-08 23:55:00.000`. I want to select all the records between two specific dates and times.

such like this:

```
SELECT * FROM  [table] 
WHERE time >=2014-04-08 23:53:00.000 AND time <= 2014-04-08 23:58:00.000
```

I write a SQL

```
SELECT * FROM [table]
WHERE time BETWEEN #4/19/2014 12:00:00 AM# and #4/19/2014 12:30:00 AM#
```

But this doesn't work. Error code is:

> Incorrect syntax near '12'.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
> the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
> information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: Whats wrong with your code?  You can use BETWEEN, you can also strip out the time if that doesnt matter: DATEADD(d, DATEDIFF(d, 0, GetDate()), 0)

Comment: We need to know what error you are getting or what is not working

Comment: You are getting an incorrect syntax error because it is incorrect date format. The answers below show you the valid format for specifying a date literal in a SQL query.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need single quotes around the values:

```
SELECT * FROM  [table] 
WHERE [time] >='2014-04-08 23:53:00.000' AND [time] <= '2014-04-08 23:58:00.000'
```

While I'm here, you are mistaken about how the data is formatted. The `yyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.fff` format is just a convenience shown for you by visual studio, management studio, or your query tool. Datetime columns are actually stored in a binary format that is not human readable.

Comment: It is really help, Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You need to put the datetime values in quotes. I personally also drop the milliseconds component as this has caused me problems in the past. You would also be safest to put brackets around your `time` column name so that it doesn't get treated as a restricted term.

```
SELECT * FROM  [table] 
WHERE [time] >='2014-04-08 23:53:00' AND [time] <= '2014-04-08 23:58:00'
```

Since you are specifying `>=` and `<=`, you can also simplify your statement by using the `BETWEEN` operator.

```
SELECT * FROM  [table] 
WHERE [time] BETWEEN '2014-04-08 23:53:00' AND '2014-04-08 23:58:00'
```